# How to determine the value in array which is in an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I get 100 objects (JSON) from a website, which is build like this.

```
"object" : [{
  "id": 12243,
  "name": 'Carl',
  "text": 'subheader',
  "tags": ["cars","child", "blue"],
  ...
},
{
  "id": 12245,
  "name": 'Dark',
  "text": 'subheader',
  "tags": ["cars"],
  ...
}
...
]
```

I want to get only which has the tag **child**. How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried thus far? Loop through the objects and check if the tag property contains `child`, and use `Array#filter`...

Comment: `o.object.filter(x => x.tags.includes('child'));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var objectsWithChild = json.object.filter(function(o){
    return o.tags.includes("child");
});
```

where `json` is your json string.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var objs = [{
  "id": 12243,
  "name": 'Carl',
  "text": 'subheader',
  "tags": ["cars","child", "blue"]
},
{
  "id": 12245,
  "name": 'Dark',
  "text": 'subheader',
  "tags": ["cars"]
}]
  
  
var objsWithTags = objs.filter(obj => obj.tags.indexOf('child') > -1);

console.log(objsWithTags);
```

Answer (score 0):

Christos has a cleaner way to do it, but this way might be clearer to a beginner. One way to do it would be to use nested for loops.

```
var myObjects = []

for (var i = 0; i < data.object.length; i++) {
    var ob = data.object[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < ob.tags.length; j++) {
         if (ob.tags[i] === "child") {
             myObjects.push(ob);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that after I posted this, but I figured it wouldn't hurt to leave it up.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably multiple ways to implement this.
But the main ideas are mostly the same.
Here in textual form:

1. Define a container (an array for example) for your matched objects.
2. Loop through all objects.
3. Loop through all entries of your array "tags".
4. Check if you find your desired value "child".
5. Remember your found object by adding it to your container (array).